# Java Longest word from inputs

Tags: java, string

I am a beginner-novice and I am trying to figure out why the logic for finding the largest word doesn't work.
Sometimes the output will result in the correct longest word, the first word, or more than one word.

Thanks!!

PS
I do not really care about the cases if two words of the same length, which I will work later once I figure out why this doesn't work. And once again please note I am a beginner/novice. Thanks

```html
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Word
{
    public static String word(String str)
    {
        int longestCount=0;
        int count=0;
        int newWord=0;
        String theWord="";
        ArrayList <String> longestWord= new ArrayList <String>();
        for (int i=0; i <str.length(); i++)
        {
            if (str.substring(i,i+1).equals(" "))
            {
                if (longestCount<count)
                {
                    longestCount=count;
                    theWord="";
                    theWord=""+str.substring(newWord,i);
                    newWord=i+1;
                    count=0;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        longestWord.add(theWord);
        String output="";
        for (int i=0; i<longestWord.size();i++)
            output+=longestWord.get(i);
        return output;
    }

    public static void main ()
    {
        Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
        String words= scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println(word(words));
    }
}
```

Comment: Unclear why you need substring... Can you not split words by whitespace first?

Comment: Also, you really don't need a list to store your words. Just store the longestWord and it's length when you see a longer string

Comment: When you find a word, but it isn't the longest, you still need to update `count` and `newWord`. (also, what happens if the longest word is the *last* word on the line, and there is no trailing space?)

Comment: You should step through your code in a debugger or by simply reading it and verify/validate every choice you've made. I don't really see how your code finds a single longest word.

Answer (score 2):

You are over thinking it. Just loop through the array list once, whenever you see a longer word, store the word/or its index:

```
ArrayList <String> words= new ArrayList <String>();
String currLongest = words.get(0);
for (String s : words)
    if(s.length() > currLongest.length())
        currLongest = s;
```

If your words are being passed as a single String delimited by spaces, the procedure is the same. Just split them before looping:

```
String[] words = str.split(" ");
String currLongest = words.[0];
for (String s : words)
    if(s.length() > currLongest.length())
        currLongest = s;
```

Note that there is no need to store the longest word into a list because at any point of time, there should only be *one* longest word.

Comment: thanks, im just unfamiliar with the split method. Good thing to learn!

Answer (score 1):

It'll be easier to chop up the string using split first. then you can simplify your codes to the following.

I have commented as much as I can in the code below

```
public static List<String> word(String str)
{
    String[] choppedUpWord = str.split(" ");
    int longestWordLength = 0; //we reset the longestWord if this is updated.
    ArrayList <String> longestWord= new ArrayList <String>(); //the results

    for(int i=0; i < choppedUpWord.length; i ++){
       String theWord = choppedUpWord[i];
       if(longestWordLength < theWord.length()){
           //new longest word found !
           longestWord.clear(); //remove the old entries
           longestWord.add(theWord); // add the new word in
           longestWordLength = theWord.length(); update with new length
       }else if(longestWordLength == theWord.length()){
           //same length as the longest word, do an appending.
           longestWord.add(theWord); // add the new word in 
       }
    } 

    return longestWord;
}
```

it returns a list instead of a String for the event when several words are the same length.

**edit** alternatively you can use a StringBuilder too.

```
public static String word(String str)
{
    String[] choppedUpWord = str.split(" ");
    int longestWordLength = 0; //we reset the longestWord if this is updated.
    StringBuilder longestWord= new StringBuilder(); //the results

    for(int i=0; i < choppedUpWord.length; i ++){
       String theWord = choppedUpWord[i];
       if(longestWordLength < theWord.length()){
           //new longest word found !
           longestWord.setLength(0); //remove the old entries
           longestWord.append(theWord); // add the new word in
           longestWordLength = theWord.length(); //update with new length
       }else if(longestWordLength == theWord.length()){
           //same length as the longest word, do an appending.
           longestWord.append(" "); //add a spacing between each word (or any delimiter that you like)
           longestWord.add(theWord); // add the new word in 
       }
    } 

    return longestWord.toString();
}
```

Comment: Clears stuff up. I tend to overthink and I want to learn how to simplify code. Thanks for the help and effort. I learned a lot from this.